# can't access service reference of wcf service in wp7?

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-phone-7

i m developing wp7 application in which i have to take service reference of wcf sevice from website.

but problem is that when i take reference it will allowed to do that but the client classes of service are not display in project & as well it not allowed to create client object of service contract.

below is my service

```
public class Mobile : IViewUser, IViewCategory
{
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public string Test(string data)
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

& this is my web.config setting

```
<behavior name="Mobile.MobileBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
<service behaviorConfiguration="Mobile.MobileBehavior"       name="BusinessFinder.Web.Services.Mobile">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="BusinessFinder.Web.Services.IMobile" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />      
</service>
```

please any one help me.

Comment: Where are you looking for the "client classes of service"? They are all normally generated together in a single file when you add the service reference.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the service reference click on the Advanced Tab on the bottom left.

Check Always generate message contracts,

and to be save deselect the Reuse types in referenced assemblies.

This should make sure that you get the WCF Objects on your client side.

EDIT:

Looking over your service again I think something is wrong.

A service Contract needs to be implement first. This needs to be an Interface sometihng like

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyNewService
{
[OperationContract]
void DoWork()
}
```

Then you need to implement a class that uses that interface

```
public class MyNewService : IMyNewService
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

right click on the service reference. then go to configure service reference. then uncheck reuse types in referenced assemblies checkbox. upd

this solved mine, hope it will help somebody else too